# Fragment cache can't modify frozen object error rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, dalli

I am trying to implement fragment caching in a `Rails 3.0.19` application and ussing `dalli` as cache store. Here is my cache fragment script:

```
- @presentations.each do |p|
  - cache "presentation", p do
    = render_presentation_object p
```

`render_presetnation_object` actually render out specific partial based on some conditions. I also added a sweeper into my controller.

```
cache_sweeper :presentation_sweeper, :only => [:create, :update, :destroy]
caches_action :update
```

Here is the code for sweeper:

```
class PresentationSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Presentation

  def after_save(presentation)
    expire_cache(presentation)
  end

  def after_update(presentation)
    expire_cache(presentation)
  end

  def after_destroy(presentation)
    expire_cache(presentation)
  end

  def expire_cache(presentation)
    expire_fragment "presentation", presentation
  end
end
```

When I try to update any thing from controller using this code `@presentation.update_attributes(params[:presentation])` , it gave an error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (RuntimeError: can't modify frozen object:`

Is there any thing I am missing out?

Comment: and the rest of the error?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (RuntimeError: can't modify frozen object: INSERT INTO 'user_logins' ('email', 'sign_in_at') VALUES ('myemail@gmail.com', '2013-01-15 19:50:55')):

Comment: whats that got to do with Presentations?

Comment: I cached the presentation partial and wrote its sweeper, but error just came up from any of record creation even does not relate to `Presentation` model.

Comment: Last time i was logged on so was getting error on presentation updating, and when i try to logout and relogin and it requries to create a user log same error occured.

Comment: Any of SQL operation which involves INSERT or UPDATE generate the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A gem **rack-mini-profiler** http://miniprofiler.com/ was doing some run-time changes to AR which was causing the issue. Removing that gem solved the issue and every thing works great now.

Comment: Had created an issue, so look at the link for more updates on it https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/issues/106

Answer (score 0):

Further to Nazar Hussain's answer. By adding ?pp=disable to the end of your website URL this will disable the miniprofiler which may allow you to test wether it is Miniprofiler causing the issue